# Select query in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two models and a `dbcontext`:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; } 
}

public class Conversation
{
    public int ConversationId { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class ChatContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }    
}
```

I am trying to add a conversation entity so I need to retrieve the `UserId` from `User` table. So far I have:

```
var newtext = new Conversation()
{
    Text = message, // message is sent from user
    UserId = ChatContext.User.Where(u => u.UserName == name).Select(u => u.UserId)  
};
```

I need to query the user table to retrieve the `userId` associated with that particular name. How should I achieve this? The error is:

> ChatContext does not have a definition for user.

Comment: Try users: UserId = ChatContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name).UserId;

Comment: @SteveGreene it says an object refrence is required for nonstatic field or property chatcontext.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firstly:** You must add `static` to `Users` like this:

```
public class ChatContext : DbContext
{
   public static DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Conversation> Conversations { get; set; }
}
```

**Secondly:** You must add `FirstOrDefault` method to your query, Because it will return an `iQueryable` like this:

```
var newtext = new Conversation()
{
   Text = message, // message is sent from user
   UserId = ChatContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == name).UserId
};
```

This should works.

Comment: it says user does not contain a definition for firstordefault

Comment: add using System.Linq;

Comment: var newuser = new User()
                {
                    UserName = name

                };
                using (var context = new ChatContext())
                {
                    context.Users.Add(newuser);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }     now this is giving me an error that users cannot be accessed with an instance refrence.

Comment: I changed users to static and added system.linq. but now I am getting a different error a another part of my code saying that user cannot be accessed with an instance refrence

Comment: you can't access static members with instance. Try this: ChatContext.Users.Add(newuser);

Comment: I am not getting any syntax error anymore but although the "name" exists in user table, the query is not returning any UserId.

Comment: Yes I do have the data in user table. Thanks a lot for your help